# Assigning a sequence number to a set

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The record set consists of 3 record types 01,11,19.

| recType | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 8888 |
| 11 | asssff |
| 19 | 78292 |
| 01 | 77777 |
| 11 | aslasd |
| 19 | 08325 |

I want to create a '''sequence''' column so that I have unique identifier for recordset. I tried '''groupby''' and '''aggregate''' but I am not getting what I desired. The desired output dataframe is as below:

| recType | Value | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 8888 | 1 |
| 11 | asssff | 1 |
| 19 | 78292 | 1 |
| 01 | 77777 | 2 |
| 11 | aslasd | 2 |
| 19 | 08325 | 2 |

kindly help.

Comment: because spark is distrubuted, there might come a case where `asssff` might come after `77777` (be in seq 2) and not `8888` (be in seq 1). is are any field that can identify the order of the dataframe?

Comment: Hello @samkart, the dataframe can only be order on recType field. It starts with 01 and ends with 19. The 01 recType represents the start of a new record set. Actually its fixed width file with multiple record types. So we are trying to group a record set  by adding a new column named '''sequence'''.

Comment: If you mix all the rows, how you will know which 01 will go to the first sequence? 7777 or 8888?

Comment: Hello @ZygD, this is how the dataframe looks after it is read from the text file. The sequence of 01 is as per the text file.

Comment: are you reading it directly in spark or first reading in pandas (fwf)?

Comment: Reading it(text file) in pyspark using dataframe reader

Comment: try emulating partition behavior with the following -- `data_sdf.coalesce(1).repartition(3).show()` -- how does the dataframe look like now?

Answer (score 0):

Here I make an assumption the order will always be replicated. If it won't, give a suitable sample putting into consideration the queries raised in comments below the question

```
new = (df.withColumn('sequence', collect_list('recType').over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)))#Put all recType in a list starting from all before to current
       #Check if recType exists in the new list.This will return a bool.
       #Cast bool into integer and sum all elements in the array
       .withColumn('sequence', expr("aggregate(transform(sequence, c-> cast(c == recType as int)),0, (k,l)->k+l)")) 
      
      ).show(truncate=False)


+-------+------+--------+
|recType|Value |sequence|
+-------+------+--------+
|01     |8888  |1       |
|11     |asssff|1       |
|19     |78292 |1       |
|01     |77777 |2       |
|11     |aslasd|2       |
|19     |08325 |2       |
+-------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it is working fine.

```
df = df.withColumn("mnId", monotonically_increasing_id())
convertUDF = udf(lambda z: z.count(1))
rec_per_block = df.count()
df = df.withColumn("block", (col("mnId") / rec_per_block).cast("int"))
w_with_block = Window.partitionBy("block").orderBy("mnId")
df = df.withColumn('sequence', collect_list('recType').over(w_with_block)) 
df = df.withColumn("sequence", convertUDF(col("sequence")))
df = df.drop("mnId", "block")
```